# やばたにえん(yabatanien) explanation?

Tags: grammar, usage, slang

So, I've come across the phrase やばたにえん online a couple of times, and I can't seem to find what it means. Multiple online translators fail to give me a translation, and searching on google for the answer only returnes this page: https://fastjapan.com/en/p207796 . It says that it is a deviation of やばい and that it can also be used with other adjectives like つらい into つらたにえん.

My question is, what does this ～たにえん suffix mean, how it's built, and when do I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

やばたにえん is described in [this Nicopedia entry](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%84%E3%81%B0%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AB%E3%81%88%E3%82%93). This is a net meme and you don't have to take it seriously. ～たにえん itself is an almost meaningless "suffix" which was coined arbitrarily because it sounded like ながたにえん (永谷園, a famous food company). Someone felt simple やばい is too uninteresting, and started to say [やばたん](https://meaning.jp/posts/895), and then やばたにえん, hoping it will sound cute or funny. Technically speaking, this may be seen as an attempt to create a new diminutive or augmentative.

This word will probably be forgotten within 5 years, and I don't think I'll ever use it myself. This word is not something you try to use intentionally. If you're a type of person who needs to use this, you'll learn how to use it without asking here.

Comment: Perhaps okie-*dokie* and easy-*peasy* are similar examples in English. Similar examples in Japanese can be found [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/地口#掛詞の技法を使い、後に意味のない言葉をつなげたもの（国語学では「むだ口」という）) although most of them are outdated.

Comment: やばたん here reminds me of やばたん⑥ which is probably completely unrelated

Answer (score 4):

Net forums do this all the time. It's like in English, if instead of saying "that's awesome!", you said "that's awesomesauce!". The suffix really means nothing, and they're just trying to be humorous. If you want to have a deeper understanding of the joke, you need to do some research into the origins of the phrase. [Nico Nico's net slang dictionary](http://dic.nicovideo.jp) can be a useful resource sometimes. Googling for "word/phrase 由来" could also yield some results. More often than not, you'll find that it started as a joke on 2chan, a text/image board.